# Is there a way to automatically have a "rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test" after "rake db:migrate" in development environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec2, guard

Is there a way to automatically do a `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` after each `rake db:migrate` when in development environment?

I have *[guard](https://github.com/guard/guard)* and *[guard-rspec](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec)* running, and I am really annoyed about the failing tests, even if it works manually in the browser.

It costs me at least 15 minutes every time I had a pause from development, to figure out that I simply forgot to call `rake db:migrate:test` after the change of the database.

Since I am already using *guard* I thought about adding *[guard-rake](https://github.com/rubyist/guard-rake)* to the project also, but I dont know which file I should watch. When watching **development.sqlite3**, `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` would be fired every time I do something with my records through the browser, so this is not really what I want.

Can someone help me with my problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Possibly just make a command alias in your `.bashrc` file.

*~/.bashrc*

```
alias rake_db_migrate='rake db:migrate db:test:prepare'
```

*Terminal*

```
$ rake_db_migrate
```

Comment: Args... Yes, simple as this... I leave the question open for a while. I hope that there will be a more ruby or rails way to do this.

Comment: Also I use `alias rake_db_migrate='rake db:migrate && rake db:migrate:test'`, so test-db is only migrated when the migration of the other one is succesfull

Comment: @NobbZ - Good call, added to my answer.

Comment: I was slaped by far to less sleep... Since there is no `db:migrate:test` task command line must be `alias rake_db_migrate='rake db:migrate && rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test'`. Already edited the answer, waiting for approval.

Comment: @ninja08 Care to elaborate on your solution?

Comment: You can possibly make your own rake task to do both if you want a more ruby way.

Comment: @CleoR: I'd personally have to say this is a "6 of one, half a dozen of the other" situation -- but yes that could be done. One would need to a add a new file in `lib/tasks/db.rake` and then `enhance` the `db:migrate` task to invoke the `db:test:prepare` task. One major issue I can see is that we've introduced unexpected behavior into the project that would affect everyone working on the project.

Comment: @DanielDoezema I like the alias solution the best, thats what I ultimately ended up doing. But if one did want a ruby way to accomplish this, you could create a new rake task (so you don't introduce unexpected behavior for everyone else) and then call the other rake tasks from within that rake task with syntax like this. 'Rake::Task["db:migrate"].invoke'

Comment: I didn't bother to read the other posts until now, but other people suggested it already.

Answer (score 4):

I use this alias:
`alias rake_db_migrate='rake db:migrate && rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test'`

because `rake db:test:prepare` is deprecated.

The reason why I use this is because our project uses pg_search (postgreSQL) along with the structure.sql (not schema.rb) and for some reason running `rake db:migrate` does not prepare the test database.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use an alias this way:

In your `~/.bashrc`

```
alias migrate='rake db:migrate && rake db:test:prepare'
```

Its easy to spend 30 minutes trying to figure why your tests are not passing only to remember you didn't reset the database. This will solve that problem.

Comment: See @Dorian's answer for a version of this that only invokes rake once by chaining tasks `alias migrate='rake db:migrate db:test:prepare'` http://stackoverflow.com/a/19503069/67834

Answer (score 2):

Faster: `alias migrate='rake db:migrate db:test:prepare'` (add this in your `.bashrc`, it will load Rails only one time)

Answer (score 2):

An option which I quite like is to override the actual task in another rake script. This will be invoked automatically after running the migration. Like this I always create an ERD diagram after I migrate the database:

```
# lib/tasks/database.rake
namespace :db do
  desc 'Additional migrate task that creates the diagram'
  task :migrate do
    if Rails.env.development?
      Rake::Task['diagram:erd'].invoke
    end
  end
end
```

So in your case:

```
# lib/tasks/database.rake
namespace :db do
  desc 'Additional migrate task that creates the diagram'
  task :migrate do
    `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`
  end
end
```

Another approach would be to run the following, which clones your new schema to the test database:

```
rake db:migrate db:test:clone
```

Comment: Good question. They reside in `lib/tasks/database.rake` in my case and they will be dynamically loaded from there. I've updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your original question of using `guard-rake`, you could watch `db/schema.rb`, as this will be updated whenever you migrate the database. However, this file will also be changed if you do a rollback, so you would likely have to pull out the migration version from the schema definition line in `db/schma.rb` or use `rake db:test:prepare` instead of `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`.

It seems like this is brittle, so using a shell alias is probably the better approach. I just wish there was a better way!

Answer (score 0):

If you feel like having this as a one-liner that just works, you can have it as:

```sh
echo "alias rake-migrate='rake db:migrate && rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test'" >> ~/.zshrc && source ~/.zshrc
```

and for the rollback there is:

```sh
echo "alias rake-rollback='rake db:rollback && rake db:rollback RAILS_ENV=test'" >> ~/.zshrc && source ~/.zshrc
```

then, just run in the terminal

```sh
rake-migrate
```

or

```sh
rake-rollback
```

**note:** this will add an alias to the `~/.zshrc` file.
**note 2:**: if you do this, say terminal1, and use another terminal tab, or vscode terminal, then just run `source ~/.zshrc` on the terminal you want to run it